# How can Perl make pattern match equal to grep -e [!] on a file

Tags: regex, perl, file-handling

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    main(@ARGV);

    sub main
    {

        open(FH,"<", 'thefile.txt') or die;
        my $filTMP=undef;
        while(<FH>){
            chomp();
            $filTMP=<FH>;
            if( $filTMP=~ /\!/){ # extracting all exclamation marks. 
        print $filTMP;

    }
    }
}
```

The problem with my newbie code is that the first matching word in the list is diplayed, but after that the angry red text "unitialized value $filetmp in patten match (m//)" shows up.  As far as I can see the $filTMP is initialized. Help is needed :).

Comment: What are you reading in from the command line?

Comment: The problem is that you reading a line (`<FH>`) in two different spots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
sub main {
    open my $file, '<', 'thefile.txt' or die;
        while(<$file>){
            chomp;
            print "$_\n" if /\!/; 
        }
}
```